# Implementing a .net core worker service orchestrator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, backgroundworker, masstransit

I have a .net core console application which currently has 1 IHostedService, i need to have multiple instances of this service spawned and managed at application startup.

I am looking to implement some kind of orchestrator which is responsible for firing up, monitoring and restarting the workers. I know the concept but i am not sure on the implementation.

The workers themselves will, through the `ICallProgService` on instantiation open a session to the proprietry database and maintain it. the workers will then listen on a message queue using the masstransit library with a request/response pattern via RabbitMq

The nuance here is that i believe(not 100% sure) that they all need to be connected to the same `IBusControl` for masstransit

The code for the worker is here:

```
public class MessageQueueWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ICallProgService _callProgService;
    private readonly IBusControl _bus;

    public MessageQueueWorker(ICallProgService callProgService)
    {
        _callProgService = callProgService;
        _bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h => { });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("callprog-service", e =>
            {
                e.Handler<ICallProgRequest>(context =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Calling Program: {context.Message.ProgramName}");
                    return context.RespondAsync<ICallProgResponse>(new
                    {
                        Result = _callProgService.CallProgProgramAsync(
                            new CallProgRequest
                            {
                                ProgramName = context.Message.ProgramName,
                                ProgramParams = context.Message.ProgramParams
                            })
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        return _bus.StartAsync(stoppingToken);
    }

    public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.WhenAll(base.StopAsync(cancellationToken), _bus.StopAsync(cancellationToken));
    }
}
```

**Program Start**

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings2.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        var builder = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices((hostcontext, services) =>
            {
                services.Configure<QmClientOptions>(config);
                services.AddSingleton<IQmClient, QmClient>();
                services.AddSingleton<ICallProgService, QmCallProgService>()
                .AddHostedService<MessageQueueWorker>();
            });

        await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
    }
```

What is the best implementation approach for the required solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are you using Microsoft's Dependency Injection and the Generic Host, I'd highly recommend following the [ASP.NET Core documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core) and let MassTransit setup and manage the bus. This will also give you health monitoring to ensure the service is operating properly (health monitoring is optional, of course).

I would also suggest using a [real consumer](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/consumers.html#consumer), and configuring it using `ConfigureConsumer(context)` so that you can leverage container scopes for each message. Using Handlers is discouraged beyond simple tests, as they don't create container scope. They work fine, but separating out consumer functionality is encouraged.

Comment: Thank you, the link you have provided looks to point me in right direction. i must of overlooked it. do you have any recommendations on the approach regarding the multiple workers using MT? 

a request/response pattern is needed here and not a pub/sub.

Presumably i need one Bus shared over the worker instances? would i need multiple instances of the consumer etc. does MT handle this? 

It would be great if you could provide a conceptual example

Thanks

Comment: MassTransit will create multiple consumer instances up to the limit configured on the receive endpoint. Your requestor could use the request client to interact with the consumer, that can also be added using the AddRequestClient configuration method.

Comment: Thank you. just to be clear here. the following logic is required 

1 consumer = 1 active session on the database which is created upon application start and maintained,

So is the solution here to let MT act as the orchestrator. register multiple instances of the same consumer each with its own connected session to the DB?